# THREE.js/WebGL Make Perspective Camera zoom out until all objects are visible

Tags: three.js

I have a slider controlling the number of items in a row to display, each is w units wide and d units tall, eventually, they go off screen, how can I dynamically zoom so that

A) all items span a specific number of units
B) all items span a specific number of pixels (to make it responsive)

I tried using the code from here:
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-how-do-we-size-something-using-screen-pixels/1177

One solution is to iterate over the objects in the scene, apply frustum intersection, and keep zooming out if it's not. I can't think of a non iterative solution, that still uses a perspective camera.

Any help appreciated.

But it bruteforces the values, and secondly it is inaccurate at large numbers

Answer (score 0):

There is some code [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-obj.html) that maybe shows a solution. Basically you can use

```
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);
```

To compute a box that contains the entire scene or some sub tree

You can then get the size and center of the box with

```
const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
```

Then you can compute how far you need to put the camera from the center of the box for it to fit on screen with

```
const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = boxSize * 0.5;
const halfFovY = THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
```

`distance` is now how are you need to put the camera away from the center of the box to view the entire box. (or rather to have the center of the box fit on screen). There's a sphere of points that distance from a point so it's up to you to pick one. For example boxCenter + [0, 0, distance] would put the camera down the z-axis from the center of the box.